# Does the phrase "literary servility" have a negative meaning in this paragraph

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Following paragraph is from the novel *We* by Yevgeny Zamyatin:

> Antagonised by Zamyatin's insistence on telling the truth as he saw it, by his open disdain for anything that smacked of literary servility.

I know servility means a willingness to serve. But in the above paragraph, it appears that "literary servility" has been used as something bad.

So, what is the meaning of literary servility in the above paragraph?

Comment: What is the source of the sentence? I think it should be "...anything **that** smacked of literary servility".

Comment: @CinCout You are right. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literary [means](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/literary) connected with literature. Servility, as you rightly mentioned, [is](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/servility) the eagerness to serve and please someone, which in itself portrays negativity.

Hence, the phrase literary servility, refers to producing literature which is too eager to serve (in this case, serve the establishment or the ruling party).

Conclusively, Zamyatin didn't respect such works of literature which praised the establishment without criticizing them.

Comment: Servility is not just willingness/eagerness to serve, but over-eagerness to do so. It has a negative connotation even by itself.

Comment: @Katy nice catch. Answer edited.